# How to change local variable in view with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I was wondering if it is possible to change a variable in a view with javascript when a certain link or button is clicked.

For example if you have something like this
`@{int number = 0;}` in the view.

Can you change the value of number with javascript/jQuery?

Comment: if its a  javascript variable then you can

Comment: What view engine you're using??

Comment: @MartinSiagian Razor

Comment: I don't think you can't access the variable from Razor using Javascript. You should put it on javascript variable then you can modify it easily.

Comment: You'd have to use SignalR to do something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor engine when renders the view, executes all the C# code on the server side and sends plain HTML (with js/css etc) to the browser. So once the view (or the page) is in the browser, all you have access to is JvaScript variables. If you want to send value of a JavaScript variable to server, you have to use either a form submit or ajax call.